# how can I design a custom node_match function in networkx to allow some nodes to be interchangeable?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

My question is simple.
I'm using networkx to build graphs from protein structures. I'm using subgraph_is_isomorphic() function but I need to allow only some amino acids to be considered equal. For example, LEU should be considered equal to ILE but not to TRP. How can I define a custom node_match function to do this?

In the following code, I need a node_match function that if used, G1 and G2 become isomorphic but not otherwise.

```
G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_node(1, label = 'ARG')
G1.add_node(2, label = 'LEU')
G1.add_edge(1, 2)

G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_node(1, label = 'ARG')
G2.add_node(2, label = 'ILE')
G2.add_edge(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your custom `node_match` function, and pass it as a parameter when you initialize the [`GraphMatcher`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html#graph-matcher) object.

```
from networkx.algorithms.isomorphism import GraphMatcher

amm = [
    {'A', 'B', 'C'}, # A == B == C
    {'E', 'F', 'G'}, # E == F == G
    {'H', 'I'},      # H == I
]

def node_match(u, v):
    return next((True for s in amm if u['label'] in s and v['label'] in s), False)

gm = GraphMatcher(G1, G2, node_match=node_match)
gm.subgraph_is_isomorphic()
```

In the `amm` list you can create many sets, one for each group of amminoacids to be considered equal. In your example:

```
>>> amm = [
...     {'LEU', 'ILE'},
...     {'ARG'},
...     {'TRP'},
... ]
>>> gm = GraphMatcher(G1, G2, node_match=node_match)
>>> gm.subgraph_is_isomorphic()
True
```

If you want to speed things up a bit you can do this:

```
amm = [
    {'A', 'B', 'C'}, # A == B == C
    {'E', 'F', 'G'}, # E == F == G
    {'H', 'I'},      # H == I
]
match = {a: s for s in amm for a in s}

def node_match(u, v):
    return v['label'] in match[u['label']]
```